# Return void func from func in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift. I'm trying to return void(in Java terminology) func from another func in Swift, but I get strange output:

```swift
func returnVoidFunc() -> (() -> ()) {
    func innerOne() {
        print("Hello from inside")
    }
    return innerOne
}

var initFunc = returnVoidFunc()
print(initFunc())
```

output is:

```
Hello from inside
()
```

Why I've got `()` and how to return void func correct?

Comment: well, you print the result of `initFunc()`, which returns void by your definition, so the print behaves as expected. what did you expected to see there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returnVoidFunc` correctly returns a `() ->()` function, `initFunc` is a reference to that function.

The reason you see `()` printed is because you are evaluating `initFunc`, and since it returns `()`, and that's what's printed.

In Swift, by the way, `()` is basically the same as `Void`.